# Firebase Storage Web: How to upload a file

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-storage

I added the following function to my website. I am using Firebase Storage but for some reason it seems as if it is not working and I have no idea why.

When you upload a file the progress bar should  show the progress of saving/uploading the file to Firebase Storage but that is not the case. Firebase has been initialized and I know it works.

I would greatly appreciate if someone could help me and tell me why the function is not working as described above and how to fix it.

```
function AddMed() {
        var uploader = document.getElementById("uploader");
    var fileButton = document.getElementById("fileButton");
    var email = sessionStorage.getItem("email");
  //Listen for file selection

    fileButton.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    // Get File 
        var file = e.target.files[0];
    //Create a storage ref

        var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('file/' + file.name);
    /** folder name will be email, 
    Will have to transfer variable from page to page and files will be .jpeg**/
    //Upload file 

        var task = storageRef.put(file);
    //Update progress bar

        task.on('state_changed',
                function progress(snapshot) {
                var percentage = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
                uploader.value = percentage;
            },
            function complete() {

                    });
    });

}
```

Comment: Is the upload process working and you want the progress bar working or the whole process?

Comment: @maximilian_cs the whole process isn't working

Answer (score 36, accepted):

1. First change the security Rules

```js
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth == null;
    }
  }
}
```

2. Create a file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Firebase Web Basics</title>

 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,500,700" rel="stylesheet">

 <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/939e9dd52c.js"></script>

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

 <div class="mainDiv" align="right">
  <h1 align="left">Firebase File Upload</h1>
  <progress id="uploader" value="0" max="100">0%</progress>
  <input type="file" id="fileButton" value="upload"/>
 </div>



<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.7.4/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "******************************",
    authDomain: "******************************",
    databaseURL: "******************************",
    storageBucket: "******************************",
    messagingSenderId: "******************************"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
  //-------------------------------------
  
  var uploader = document.getElementById('uploader');
  var fileButton =         document.getElementById('fileButton');
  fileButton.addEventListener('change', function(e){
  var file = e.target.files[0];
  var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('img/'+file.name);
  var task = storageRef.put(file);
  task.on('state_changed', function progress(snapshot) {
    var percentage = (snapshot.bytesTransferred/snapshot.totalBytes)*100;
    uploader.value = percentage;

  }, function error(err) {


  },function complete() {

  });
});  
  
  
</script>

<script src="fileup.js">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is better than google's example: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files

Comment: Be careful with this solution. This is saying if there is no authentication in the request you can write files. That means _anyone_ can upload. Make sure that is the storage rule you want.