# How to upload file in firebase using React?

Tags: html, reactjs, firebase-storage, visual-web-developer

How to upload a saved file to firebase without taking file input from user?
I don't want to use  tags as my requirement is to store a file at the backend without taking any file input from user

```
import {useState} from 'react'; 

import storage from './firebase'; 

function App() { 

const [image , setImage] = useState(''); 
const upload = ()=>{ 

  if(image == null) 

    return; 

  storage.ref(`/images/${image.name}`).put(image) 

  .on("state_changed" , alert("success") , alert); 
} 

  

  return ( 

    <div className="App"> 

      <center> 

      <input type="file" onChange={(e)=>{setImage(e.target.files[0])}}/> 

      <button onClick={upload}>Upload</button> 

      </center> 

    </div> 

  ); 
} 

  

export default App;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase Storage Web: How to upload a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41304405/firebase-storage-web-how-to-upload-a-file)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to upload a file that the user didn't select in their browser, as that would be a major security risk. Browsers vendors and API creators worked hard to ensure that only files that the user explicitly selects can be uploaded to the server.